# Marker do not appear when I try to integrate Google Maps into an existing web page

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I previously prepare a javascript that shows  some marker downloaded in JSON format, from a webservice.

The code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>MAP</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.8"></script>

     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="map_bar.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>MAPPA</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

that calls the map_bar.js:

```
(function() {
    window.onload = function() {

        // Creating a new map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(80.650535,41.886146),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
        function createPoints(json){
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // Looping through the JSON data
        for (var i = 0, length = json.locations.length; i < length; i++) {

                var data = json.locations[i],
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long);
        console.log(data.long);
            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.nombre,
            icon: 'beer.png'
                });


            (function(marker, data) {
                // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            info = data.nombre+'<br/>'+data.offerta+'<br/>'+data.horario;
                        infoWindow.setContent(info);   //esto escibe las info
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            })
            (marker, data);

         }

        }


        // Get  the JSON data from PHP script

    var json ;
        $.getJSON("http://mywebservice.php").done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);   
        json = data;
        createPoints(json);
    });

    }

})();
```

It works, but the  problem appears when I trying to integrate that in an existing webpage. 
I have some sections and putting the same code in my "map section", the map appears but not markers.

The console.log(data) into the getJSON method not give back the point. It strange because the same code works in a "stand alone" page.

Any idea about that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the "non-working" page look like?  Does it also have an onload function?  You can only have one...

Comment: Thank for answer! the page uses fancybox plugin. Could it be this the reason?

Comment: Yes, it could be, but how are we supposed to tell?  You still haven't provided the code that _doesn't_ work.

Comment: thanks. I didn't provide de the entire web page because is quite long. I try to exclude fancy lib but problems still...

Comment: Make a smaller version of the page that exhibits the problem.  You may find the problem by doing that, if not, when you post that page we can be more helpful.

Comment: I just realize that the SAME page, google map markers appears  if url is domain.com/MYPAGE  AND no if url is mypage.domain.com (that is the url that I use as Subdomain). What could it depend on? is very strange...

Comment: Now It works. The issue was the subdomain. I do not Know the reason,  but from subdomain,  the code: "$.getJSON("http://mywebservice.php").done(function(data)"   was not reachable. So I just copy the php method into the subdomain and than the webservice  is reachable now. Thanks for your interest  geocodezip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery getJSON is subject to [the same origin policy](http://e-mats.org/2010/01/jquery-getjson-and-the-same-origin-policy/), a sub-domain is not the same domain as the main domain.

Using a relative reference to a file in the sub-domain fixes the issue.